# Nested sum with dependent summation variables

Tags: summation

The following identity involves a reversal of order of summations. It seems to be correct when I tried through some examples. The sagecell code for verifying some examples is [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVj88KwjAMh--FvkNgh7Vugh2ehL2EV3FQ6KYDrSPVsb69_TO36U7mFJKQ3_clx7qv0bT6AuZ1N5QYASXsKMFyT4l1fS-RpTbllCQNk1uVK-6mQ-V7DhuwlaKkeSDIW3eV0GpAqS81MJFjJviBEnDlD9TXMpzPB75cdlb6z361-B7mno-dhirGrAPHvLMD7bDVT2bE1Hr4lWgRRddkARsi1kz_k6aWdtNhsCiixcg_2YTIj4f9w6Pgb5llcsQ=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). But how to give a proof for this? $$\sum\limits_{a=1}^r\sum\limits_{d=1}^a f(a-d,d)+\sum\limits_{a=1}^r f(a,0) =\sum\limits_{d=1}^r\sum\limits_{a=d}^r f(d,a-d)+\sum\limits_{a=1}^r f(0,a)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(0,0)$ as some dummy value, if it is not defined. The LHS can then be written as
$$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{a=1}^r \sum_{d=0}^a f(a-d, d) &= \sum_{a=1}^r \sum_{d=0}^a f(d, a-d)
 \\
&= \sum_{a=0}^r \sum_{d=0}^a f(d, a-d) - f(0,0) \\
(\ast) &= \sum_{d=0}^r \sum_{a=d}^r f(d, a-d) - f(0,0) \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^r \sum_{a=d}^r f(d, a-d) + \sum_{a=0}^r f(0,a) - f(0,0) \\
&= \sum_{d=1}^r \sum_{a=d}^r f(d, a-d) + \sum_{a=1}^r f(0,a).
\end{align*}$$
The equality labelled $(\ast)$ is a classic swap of nested sums. Basically, the double sum iterates over all pairs $(a,d)$ such that $0 \leq d \leq a \leq r$, so the two different conventions represent first fixing $a$, versus first fixing $d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know the reason for the swap of $a-d$ and $d$ in the first step? Is this a standard technique?

Comment: @VishnuNamboothiriK $\sum_{d=0}^a f(a-d, d) = f(a,0) + f(a-1,1) + f(a-2,2) + \cdots + f(1, a-1) + f(0,a)$ - there is symmetry in the terms.

Answer (score 0):

> A variation: We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{a=1}^r}&\color{blue}{\sum_{d=0}^af(a-d,d)}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{a=1}^r\sum_{d=0}^af(d,a-d)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq d\leq a\leq r}f(d,a-d)+\sum_{a=1}^rf(0,a)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{d=1}^r\sum_{a=d}^rf(d,a-d)+\sum_{a=1}^rf(0,a)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we merge the sums by starting the index of the inner sum with $d=0$.
- In (2) we change the order of summation of the inner sum $d\to a-d$.
- In (3) we separate the sum with $d=0$. We also write the index region of the double sum somewhat more conveniently as preparation for the next step.
- In (4) we exchange inner and outer sum by setting index limits according to the inequality chain of the index region from (3).